# Drag and drop ftp file upload web widgets

Tags: upload, ftp

It seems like drag and drop upload widgets disappeared from the face of Web 2.0. The last one of these I remember using was an activex widget, and inability of using it in anything other than IE doomed it. Have you used or seen one of these recently?

Answer (score 2):

The [Dojo Toolkit](http://dojotoolkit.org/) JavaScript library supports some drag & drop functionality that I've seen work in IE6+ and FF2+. The nice thing about Dojo and other JS libraries is that they abstract away all of the browser detection stuff.

I'm sure other JS libraries support this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

[FTP Drop](http://widgets.yahoo.com/widgets/ftp-drop) for Yahoo Widgets allows you to drag files over the widget and the file will be sent to the defined ftp server.

Answer (score 1):

Our current project makes heavy use of drag+drop, using [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) and [gwt-dnd](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-dnd/) you can do some very cool stuff. Standards based, and works in IE6, Safari, Firefox, Opera, etc..

The issue of how to transmit a file is a separate one I believe.

As for FTP support, I see that as being mostly replaced with HTTP File Upload support.

In the case you need more flexibility (progress bar, multiple file selection), then you can make use of flash to do this. You can use Javascript to interact with an invisible flash app which performs the file transfer. YUI's file upload control does this. You can see an example on Flickr's enhanced upload page.

We've built a custom version designed for use with GWT apps. Same concept.

Answer (score 1):

You can upload to FTP in browser with an applet such as JFileUpload.
See: http://www.jfileupload.com/products/jfileupload/index.html

[Disclosure: This is my site]

It supports regular FTP, FTPS (explicit and implicit) and SFTP (FTP + SSH). It can resume broken transfer too.

Applets can be moved outside browser since JRE 1.6.0_10.